# XmlSerializers.dll did not succeed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, plugins, office-2010

> Name: AIT.OurPluginOffice.Office2010.ExcelAddIn
>   From: file:///C:/Program Files/OurPlugin/OurPlugin Office 2010/AIT.OurPluginOffice.Office2010.ExcelAddIn.vsto
>
> `************** Exception Text **************
>   System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException: Downloading file:///C:/Program Files/OurPlugin/OurPlugin Office 2010/AIT.OurPluginOutlook2010.XmlSerializers.dll did not succeed. ---> System.Net.WebException: Could not find file 'C:\Program Files\OurPlugin\OurPlugin Office 2010\AIT.OurPluginOutlook2010.XmlSerializers.dll'. ---> System.Net.WebException: Could not find file 'C:\Program Files\OurPlugin\OurPlugin Office 2010\AIT.OurPluginOutlook2010.XmlSerializers.dll'. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Program Files\OurPlugin\OurPlugin Office 2010\AIT.OurPluginOutlook2010.XmlSerializers.dll'.
>      at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>      at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
>      at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
>      at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean useAsync)
>      at System.Net.FileWebStream..ctor(FileWebRequest request, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare sharing, Int32 length, Boolean async)
>      at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
>      at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponseCallback(Object state)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Net.FileWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponse()
>      at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.DownloadAddIn(TimeSpan timeout)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()`

I've replaced some key points with 'OurPlugin'

First I tried addin in this XmlSerializers, because I couldn't find it. It says it is missing it - so I must be needing it. A couple of iterations later (not to mention gray hair, headaches, torn hair, a few million rebuilds and google hits/attacks, btw I'm on day 4 with this one) - I'm trying to remove it, because I don't need it.

The Office 2007 build is running smooth as ever, just the Office 2010 thats bugging me.

- I found the bytes.com - where kevin.morrison says exclude it, no such option in 4.0.
- I found the VSTO Runtime setup registry.
- I got the office2010pia_bootstrapper.exe
- I found the /Publish/Prerequisites/ [v] MS Visual Studio 2010 Tools For Office Runtime (x86 and x64)

I did a copy paste of registry keys from the 2007 solution, added the Custom actions (Register and Unregister).

I got a virtual XP with 2010 to test on. [x] "Shut down and delete changes".

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it.

Go to Properties - Build - Generate serialization assembly - change from Auto to Off